# Cannot close popup js box

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, popup

I need help closing a popup tab. The overlay div is z-indexed so it's not hiding the close div. Here's my code:

```
<div id='mail'>                 
  <div id="popup-overlay"></div>
   <div class="close-popup"">
  <a>X</a>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
    var mail = $('#mail');
    var overlay = $('#popup-overlay.' + pageID);
    var mailClose = $('#mail.' + pageID + ' .close-popup');

    mailClose.on('click touchstart', function(event){
    mail.removeAttr('style');
    mail.css('display', 'none');
    overlay.css('display', 'none');
  });

  mailClose.bind('mouseover', function(event){
    mailClose.css('cursor', 'pointer');
  });

  mailClose.on('blur', function(event){
      this.blur();
     });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: is there any other code that is unseen in your snippet, for example this snippet cannot run as there is an erroneous close curl brace before the last script tag, and the variable pageID is not defined.

Comment: @kieran Agreed...not to mention the redundant .blur call at the end :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there were a few things wrong with the source you have given us in the snippet, but that's probably just because you were copy pasting a subsection of your total code. These issues were: unexpected " character in the class definition of `close-popup`; variable pageID is undefined; and finally there is an extra curly brace at the end of the script.

Presumably none of these is the actual issue.

I believe the issue you are having stems from the selector you are using for the `mailClose` element. Specifically, the selector for the mailClose element is incorrect, as it has the unnecessary `#mail` element. I'm not sure what the pageID variable actually is, but as it is not present in the HTML you have given us, that will also need to be removed in order for the selector to function. Once removing those trivial bugs from the first paragraph, as well as the erroneous elements of the CSS selector, I believe I have the functionality working as expected, as demonstrated in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntdMv/). Presumably the pageID will actually be a significant value and should appropriately be added to the selector.

Feel free to edit the source and comment this answer if you would like another look at a more comprehensive example. Hope this helps,

Comment: Kieran, thanks for the fiddle. That helps a lot. And yes code was cut out piece-meal which was confusing.